# Get the clean data using dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, formula, data-cleaning

I get a table where I have ID and and description, so I only need desciption as output.

DATA:

| Language | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 9;#JS;#20;#React | 2;#Comon |
| 11;#PL/SQL | 163;#Не участвует в продуктовой команде |
| 6;#Java;#7;#Kotlin;#8;#Solidity;#9;#JS;#10;#Dart/Flutter | 164;#Умный старт;#165;#Прочее |
| 12;#Swift/ObjectiveC | 167;#FinamTrade;#168;#SuperApp;#169;#WatchList;#170;#Профиль инструмента;#171;#Кубики;#172;#Advisor + Novoadvisor;#164;#Умный старт;#173;#Технический анализ;#4;#App Банка;#188;#Личный кабинет;#174;#J2TX |

Wanted DATA:

| Language | Product |
| --- | --- |
| JS, React | Comon |
| PL/SQL | Не участвует в продуктовой команде |
| Java, Kotlin, Solidity, JS, Dart/Flutter | Умный старт, Прочее |
| Swift/ObjectiveC | FinamTrade, SuperApp, WatchList, Профиль инструмента, Кубики, Advisor + Novoadvisor, Умный старт, Технический анализ, App Банка, Личный кабинет, J2TX |

Example:

[image: Input]

I need:

[image: Output]

This is a dictionary. I can solve this through Python but I have to use Excel (formulas or VBA).
Also, you can see that delimeters are ";" but I need as output - ",".

Comment: @braX none of code were used by now, I don't see a pattern for VBA

Comment: @JvdV added sample data, I'm using 2016 version of Excel, can't upgrade to 365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom UDF you can call:

```
Function RX(s As String) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(?:^|;#)\d+;#"
    RX = .Replace(Mid(s, InStr(s, ";#") + 2), ", ")
End With

End Function
```

[image]

Use it like `=RX(A2)` etc...